# How can I allow editing in certain columns in a listview row in asp.net based on a value in another column of that row?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am trying to design listview to only allow editing of certain columns in a row based on a value in another column of the same row.  I have spent several hours attempting many things and researching on the web but to no avail.  I have tried adding a condition in the EditTemplate and tried using various listviews events such as ItemEditing and ItemDataBound, but have not succeeding.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I need to do and where?

Comment: Apply different class names on the rows that you want to edit and the ones you don't. After that use javascript to enable, disable the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past by just hiding a textbox control and showing a label control for items that i don't want to edit.

Here Item2 is only editable when Item1 = "1":

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkUpdate" Text="Update"  CommandName="Update"  />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Text="Cancel"  CommandName="Cancel"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Item1_txt" Text='<%# Eval("Item1") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Item2_txt" Text='<%# Eval("Item2") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("Item1") == "1" ? true : false %>' /> 
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="Item2_lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Item2") %>' Visible='<%#  Eval("Item1") != "1" ? true : false %>'  />                 
        </td>
    </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
```